# NGINX: Call non SSL API from SSL based Web Call (https to http call)

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, https, reverse-proxy

I have NGINX configured with SSL and angular website is hosted in it, whereas the Login API is running without SSL.
When I try logging on UI, I get below error,

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com:3333/auth/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Note : UI calls internally 'http://example.com:3333/auth/login'.
Obvously, UI in SSL and node API without SSL.
But in nginx.conf I used "proxy_pass to route traffic through port 80 (to call http://example.com:3333/auth/login the way it was called without SSL certificate) to redirect to 80 port as below,

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
        }

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name  example.com;
    location / {
           proxy_pass http://example.com:80;
    }
```

But no luck, If I remove SSL from NGINX, all works fine. Any suggestion on how to call non-SSL api from SSL based web call?

Comment: Your application contains explicit references to `http://example.com:3333/auth/login`. Having nginx proxy_pass does not magically remove the reference, you have to fix your code instead to use `https://example.com/auth/login` instead.

Comment: Hi Steffen, Thanks for your comment. Sorry for confusion as I wanted to say that reference 'http://example.com:3333/auth/login' exists without SSL, mean route through port 80. My idea was when SSL traffic arrives, wanted to route same through 80 as reverse proxy. hence I used proxy_pass http://example.com:80; to call the first server block (route via 80). Hope this should be possible as reverse-proxy can call my non-SSL API in my private zones, not necessarily run over https right? I just want to route traffic to port 80 once comes from NGINX server. Thanks

Comment: You nginx config will not make your application stop requesting `http://example.com:3333/auth/login` since this is somewhere in your code. nginx will also not magically rewrite a URL contained in your application. This needs to be fixed inside your application, not within nginx.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, proxy_pass redirects the traffic once the traffic hits NGINX right? If so, I want https traffic shoud be redicted to http, After that 'http://example.com:3333/auth/login' gets called. User-https-request:443->NGINX-entrypoint->proxy_pass-redirection(443to80)->http:80->http-API call. The backend call will remain same. Why should I update backend API here, An I missing anything here.

Comment: *"once the traffic hits NGINX right?"* - right. Only the traffic to http://example.com:3333/auth/login will never hit nginx, since the request is never executed by the browser because of mixed content - that's the error message you see . That's why I said that it needs to be fixed in the web application already.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get on this. The flow with http is Browser(http)->Nginx(http)->Ang-UI->Node-API (http) works Fine. If I add SSL on Nginx only, Browser(https)->Nginx(https)->Ang-UI->Node-API (http), So Node-API is isolated, Is there any way to say NGINX allow mixed content? Could you elaborate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nginx does not stop mixed content, the browser does. The plain HTTP request does not even reach nginx since the browser refuses to issue a plain HTTP request from inside a page loaded by HTTPS. The best is probably to make your API not use absolute URLs (i.e. `http://domain/auth/login...`) at all but only relative or path-absolute URL (i.e. `/auth/login`). In this case the browser will use domain and protocol from the loaded page.

Comment: @Steffen Thanks for your comments, that helped. Also I had to do SE linux and browser setup to allow http traffic over https. Thanks